# Could a large corporation be taken down through a massive stock sale over time?

Tags: united-states

Let's say there is a scenario that you have a large corporation which is public and trading through stock is also doing well and growing larger over time, becoming quite the competitor in its space and is over twenty-five years old, perhaps on its way to living for another twenty-five or fifty years.

If one were to get their friends and family and any future family of age to invest in stock in this corporation (buying more later at their discretion) with a sole agreement that they would hold onto their shares for at least twenty five years and they were at the end of that time committed to: a) all at once make a purchase of stock so as to increase interest and perhaps the value; and b) within a short period of time, dump all their stock invested in the past twenty-five years, could they potentially make a large corporation unstable?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to influence a company's actions by buying stock?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/72982/10997)

Comment: Not sure it's quite what you're talking about, but this may interest you: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-volkswagen-idUSTRE49R3I920081028

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "taken down"? If you mean could driving the price down crash the business, no. If you are asking whether it could put the company at risk of being bought out by someone, who might keep it or disassemble it, then possibly yes -- though there are standard ways companies manage takeover attempts so this is a definite maybe. If you are asking something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to consider who you are your family and friends are selling the shares to. You either have

- find a buyer before-hand. If that happens, then the trade will have very little effect on the market.
- Sell to dealers/brokers. In this case, the brokers are going to make sure that they don't lose money and will be sure that they will be able to sell the shares they buy at a profit. In other words, they won't give you a good price and you will lose money.
- Sell on the market when you can find buyers, which means lots of small trades made over time and the price will fall and fall. If you are selling a lot of shares, then buyers will be reluctant to buy until they think you have finished selling. So to encourage them to buy you have to sell cheap. In other words, you still lose money.

So this scenario is going to cost you and your family and friends a lot of money.

If you do start a large sell off , what **should** happen is that the share price starts to fall. Then, if this is a large publicly traded company, when the share price falls to below a certain level, other people will perceive it to be a bargain and start buying up the stock and the price stabilises.

What **can** happen is that that people start to wonder **why** the stock is being sold and begin to wonder if the sellers know something bad about the company. (That would probably be insider dealing, but it happens). So other people start selling as well and the price falls further.

Even then, there will be some people who know the true value of the company. Sometimes you get Company Directors buying shares as a show of confidence in the company and sometimes the company starts buying up their own shares. So the price stabilises.

Answer (score 0):

A massive stock dump would drive down the share price but that won't harm the corporation.